# time expressions

Tags: expressions, time

Is it correct to use 'hardly ever' at the beginning or the end of a sentence? for example is it right to say: 
Hardly ever, my parents help me with homework / my parents help me with homework hardly ever.

These don't sound right to me but my english teacher said that time expressions with more than one word should be at the beginning/end of a sentence. 
Where would you use hardly ever?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Native speakers (at least in Britain) would normally say "My parents hardly ever help me with my homework". I have hardly ever come across this phrase at the beginning or end of a sentence.

Comment: Consider this *conversation*: "Do you do your homework?" "Hardly ever." It's both at the beginning and end of the second sentence. (That aside, I agree with the answer given here.)

Answer (score 1):

"Hardly ever" is an exception. It's true that time expressions consisting of 2 and more words can be used at the beginning of a sentence (they are sometimes at the end though).

But "hardly ever" is used after the subject or after the predicate if the predicate is the verb *to b*e:

> My parents hardly ever help me with my homework.
>
> She is hardly ever happy.